# Adding and removing html elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I',m quite new with jQuery and I face a problem.

When I try to delete elements at the beginning it works, but when I add new element and then try to delete it, other siblings li elements are deleted too. 
How Can i Solve it?

That's basic structure:

```
<br/>
<b>Delete</b>
<input type="radio" id="delnod" name="action" title="Delete"/>     
<br/>  
<b>Add</b>        
<input type="radio" id="addnod" name="action" title="Add"/>
<br/>  
        <ul id="rodzic">
        <li id="xx">XX
            <ul id="cv">
                <li id="vb">aa</li>
                <li id="hh">vv</li>
                <li id="fg">cc</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="yy">YY
            <ul id="zz">
                <li id="vv">12</li>
                <li id="vx">34</li>
                <li id="vz">55</li>
            </ul>
        </li>            
    </ul>
```

And that's jQuery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul,li").click(function() {
        if ($('#delnod').is(':checked'))
        {
            if (confirm('Do you want to delete?'))
            {
                $(this).remove();
                return false;
            }
        }


        if ($('#addnod').is(':checked'))
        {

            $("<li>And me too!</li>").insertAfter(this);
   //       $(this).closest('ul').children(':last').before('<li />'); 
                return false;
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: can u create like in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `$("ul,li")` which you are using ahead of the `.click()` handler looks incorrect. It will match all `<ul>`s **and** `<li>`s, instead of just `<li>`s.

Try this instead to only match `<li>`s (which are inside a `<ul>`)

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
    ...
});
```

---

**Note:** the below point originally discovered and answered by PSL. Just editing this answer to remove the incorrectness.

Another reason is that, your newly created LIs don't have any event handler attached to them, Binding using `.on()` to a parent level element will solve it.

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Yeah (ul, li).click would mean, "when I click all the UL tags and all the li tags)

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with your click handler. when you click on newly created `li` and click on it. it doesn actually  have a click event bound to it, instead it's parent li's click event kicks in and deletes it. You can use event delegation for click event for newly added elements using `on()` .

See doc for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AWcSc/)

Try this:-

```
 $('ul').on('click' , 'li', function() {// I have provided ul as an example, You may want to attach it to the container of ul that already exists. Say a div.
             if ($('#delnod').is(':checked'))
        {
            if (confirm('Do you want to delete?'))
            {
                $(this).remove();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

With this event is attached to the `ul` and any newly created `li` will get its own click event available by delegation.

Comment: @OP - +1 This is the real reason. *The newly created LIs don't actually have a click event bound to it, instead it's parent li's click event kicks in and deletes it*

Answer (score 1):

**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VrPty/9/)**

Because you are **dynamically** create new elements, you must use `.on()` method:

```
$('body').on('click', 'ul li', function() {
    // code
});
```

And when you want to insert your new element, you must use this:

```
$("<li>And me too!</li>").appendTo($(this).closest('ul'));
```

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'ul li', function() {
        if ($('#delnod').is(':checked')) {
            if (confirm('Do you want to delete?')) {
                $(this).remove();
                return false;
            }
        }

        if ($('#addnod').is(':checked')) {
            $("<li>And me too!</li>").appendTo($(this).closest('ul'));
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

---

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 0):

You have a tree of elements there, on whichs parent you as well trigger the click event.

`$(...).click(function(e){ if (e.target !== this) { return false; } /* your code here */`

This shall ensure the click event was actually fired on exactly the desired element and neither of its child elements.

also see the API reference for stopPropagation